# Turning off the GPS updates when user hits the home button on iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-location

I have an application with four tabs.  Two of the tabs use location updates and other two don't require GPS. I use following code to turn off the location updates when the view is about to disappear

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
  }

This seems to work when I change tabs.  The puzzle is that when user hits the home button while in the tabs which do not require location information then GPS is turned off.  However if the user hits the home button while in one of the tabs that is using location updates then the GPS is left turn on.  I think it is because "viewWillDisappear" is never called when the user hits the home button.. Am I right in that assumption, any suggestion on how to fix this problem.

Soofi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the "[UIBackgroundModes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)" key to your -Info.plist but don't specify any values, that should ensure location services are not used in the background.

Comment: OK JC you the man... Blanking out the UIBackgroundModes fixed the problem.  I read through several apple docs and did not catch that.

Comment: Glad it worked :)  Don't forget to mark as answered if the solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

well, unless you've specifically set up the app to have [background services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) for gps, it won't continue running, and I'm guessing you have not done so, otherwise, you wouldn't be asking how to stop it...however, for completeness, just in case you really do want that, I think you want the applicationDidEnterBackground method

Comment: RW.. You are right I have not set up any specific background services. Interesting point though, the reason I think the GPS is turned on is because the GPS symbol remain visible in the top status bar even when the app is turned off.  I have waited as long as five minutes for it to go away and it doesn't.

Comment: maybe add `NSLog(@"got GPS data");` to your didUpdateLocation method, and see if anything actually appears in the console after you hit the home button